# MySQL query displays no results in HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to throw together a simple inventory database for a small customer of mine (I normally don't do WebDev stuff) but I'm a little stumped.  I have what I think should work, but I get no results in my table.  I know the query is good since I get the expected results when querying directly to the database, unless PHP expects different formatting of my SQL statement.  here is my page:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Inventory</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "SELECT 
            products.name,
            products.sku,
            inventory.quantityfry,
            inventory.quantityjuv,
            inventory.quantityadult,
            inventory.notes,
            inventory.location,
            inventory.owner
          FROM 
            products
          INNER JOIN 
            inventory
          ON
            products.sku=inventory.sku";

$result = mysqli_query($query);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Species</th>
<th>SKU</th>
<th>Fry Count</th>
<th>Juvie Count</th>
<th>Adult Count</th>
<th>Notes</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Owner</th>

</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantityfry'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantityjuv'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantityadult'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['owner'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page, all I see is my HTML table headers, but no data.  No error messages, either.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try passing a DB connection to your query `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`

Comment: seems to be something missing here ... $result = mysqli_query($query);

Comment: Next time, check `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't see error messages because you don't bother checking for them. You're calling `mysqli_query` incorrectly, and since you don't check for errors, never see them:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                       ^^^^---required
```

Since you used it incorrectly, the query call returns false. You then blindly try to fetch result rows from that boolean FALSE, which would lead to further errors and your `while()` loop never executing at all.

Comment: [Exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747062/mysql-query-displays-no-results-in-html-table-with-php#comment31088882_20747062)

Comment: Thanks Marc B.
This is the first time I have used mysqli functions in PHP, so I'm not surprised that I missed that.  Is there anything else I'm missing, or should be doing differently?

Comment: Nothing really wrong with the code, other than the $con stuff. Stylistically, you might want to investigate breaking out of PHP mode to output "fixed" chunks of HTML/text, or at least using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) instead of multi-line echoes. But, that's just stylistic things.

Comment: @tycoonbob Yes, you miss the `htmlspecialchars` calls when outputting text in an HTML-context.